# how to convert the different date formate into same format

Tags: sql, date, netezza

```
A               B
203105144092    02/14/2015
203105144092    2015-08-10
203105144092    2015-08-03
203105144092    05/11/2015
203105144092    09/30/2014
```

how to convert B col into `yyyy-MM-DD`

Comment: how many format are in B? and what are those formats? What field type is  B? Also please read http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: SQL date functions are non-standard.  What SQL database is this?

Comment: @Schwern tag say netezza

Answer (score 0):

In your case you can use a combination of an implicit CAST to DATE and then the TO_CHAR function, like so:

```
TESTDB.ADMIN(ADMIN)=> TESTDB.ADMIN(ADMIN)=> select col, to_char(col::date,'YYYY-MM-DD') from date_test;
    COL     |  TO_CHAR
------------+------------
 05/11/2015 | 2015-05-11
 02/14/2015 | 2015-02-14
 2015-08-10 | 2015-08-10
 2015-08-03 | 2015-08-03
 09/30/2014 | 2014-09-30
(5 rows)
```